# make asp fileupload compatible with evry browser

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

I am using ASP fileupload control. When I run my code in different browsers, the looks of fileuplaod gets changed.

Is there any way to keep its looks constant in each browser, no matter which version of browser I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

Nope!

In short, if you use the standard file browser control, it WILL look different in various browsers.

The point it though, if someone uses Firefox, it will look like all other file browsers that they see and so on. So, while it may not be consistent for you, it will be consistent from the perspective of the actual users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flash to handle the file upload. And create a control that will look the same in every browser.

Comment: Still, you shouldn't abuse Flash for a thing like this.